# Android resize an ImageButton without losing the clarity of the image

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I added an ImageButton into my relative layout, my xml code is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomePageActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/book" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As log as the width and height are wrap_content, the image is clear, but when I specify a larger width and height like:

```
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
```

then, when running on the AVD the image button loses clarity.
Is there any solution??

Comment: What dimensions does `book.png` have?

Comment: book.png has the dimensions of standard drawable files (hdpi, mdpi, ...). I added the image to the ImageButton by creating new icon and it dropped automatically in the drawable files.

Comment: how to set a ninepatch image please ??

Comment: if you mean the original dimensions of book.png, then they are 1362x1190

Answer (score 1):

By default `ImageView`/`ImageButton` will scale the image to fit center.

You can change that by using `android:scaleType = "center"`. This will make image retain its original size and keep it centered.

If the image is not a picture of an object but just a rectangular shape, convert it to a 9-patch drawable.